# How to Load a .dump File Format Using manage.py loaddata in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-mysql

I have a `data.dump` file for mysql and am trying to use `manage.py loaddata`to fill my db with this data file, but getting this error:

`CommandError: Problem installing fixture '˜/Downloads/data': dump is not a known serialization format.`

Apparently this is not a known format for Django loaddata. The question is how I can convert a .dump to .json, so I can use it with loaddata command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you crated your data.dump via MySQL there is, AFAIK, no way to load it via `manage.py loaddata`.

You can use this command to import so-called "fixtures" created with `manage.py dumpdata`

You will have to import your MySQL data dump directly into your new MySQL database.